# What determines which More button an option shows in?

Tags: openerp-7

In OpenERP there is the `More` button in the tree view, and the `More` button in the form view.  Sometimes options show in one, or the other, or both -- what determines which one an option shows in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which `<More>` button an option is available in is determined by the table:field `ir.actions.act_window`:`multi` and `ir.values`:`key2` pair.

The `<act_window>` shortcut (which makes the option available only in the **form view `More`**) looks like this:

```
<act_window
    name="My Custom Name Here"
    id="model_table_whatever_name"
    res_model="model.table"
    src_model="another_model.table"
    />
```

which, by default, also sets:

```
    multi = False
    key2 = 'client_action_relate'
    view_type = 'form'
    view_mode = 'tree,form'
    target = 'current'
```

The value combinations/results of `multi`/`key2`are:

```
multi  /   key2                  -->  tree More / form More
0      /   client_action_relate  -->    No      /   Yes
1      /   client_action_relate  -->    Yes     /   No
1      /   client_action_multi   -->    Yes     /   No
0      /   client_action_multi   -->    Yes     /   Yes
```

If you need/want more control over all the fields created in the two tables that the shortcut effects:

```
<record id="action_model_table_whatever_name" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">My Custom Name Here</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">model.table</field>
    <field name="src_model">another_model.table</field>
    <field name="multi" eval="0"/>
    ... more fields here ...
</record>

<record id="model_table_whatever_name" model="ir.values">
    <field name="name">My Custom Name Here</field>
    <field name="model">sample.request</field>
    <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.act_window,' + str(ref('action_model_table_whatever_name'))"/>
    <field name="key2">client_action_relate</field>
    ... more fields here ...
</record>
```

**Note:**  While the default `key2` value in the `act_window` shortcut is `'client_action_relate'`, the default value for `key2` when using the `record` format is `'tree_but_open'` -- so you can omit it when using the shortcut, but you must include it when using the `record` style.